# Prefix filename with LasWriteTime based on filetype

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to append the lastwrite time (last file content modification time) timestamp into the filename of **select media filetypes** only, from different camera models. The pattern would be: `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS__origfilename.ext`.

For example, **before** and **after** the rename:

```
origfilename.jpg             >   20011231_235959__origfilename.jpg
origfilename2.png            >   origfilename2.png     #.txt is not a "media_file"
```

The filetypes to timestamp are defined in a nested dictionary and called with `config[camID]["media_file"]` for each camera type :

**Code** (last line gives syntax error):

```
config = {
    'nd5': {},
    'g7': {},
    'alpha9': {},
}
config['nd5']['media_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
config['g7']['media_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')
config['alpha9']['media_file'] = ('jpg')    

root = "."     
def get_last_write_time(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    convert_time_to_human_readable = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
    return convert_time_to_human_readable

timestr = convert_time_to_human_readable

for camID in config:
    for dir in next(os.walk(root))[1]:
        if dir.endswith(camID):
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)):
                for f in files:
                    if any([f.lower().endswith(x) for x in config[camID]["media_file"]]):
                        os.rename(os.path.join(path, f) 
                        os.path.join(path, "%s" % timestr+'_'+f))
```

Tree showing the =camID (=key1, the string after the last `=` in the directory name) and the filetypes to append timestamp:

```
└───CWD
    ├───001=nd5
    │   └───DCIM
    │       ├───125NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    │       ├───126NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    │       └───127NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    ├───002=nd5
    │   └───DCIM
    │       ├───201NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    │       ├───202NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    │       └───203NCD5     ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
    ├───003=g7
    │   └───DCIM
    │       ├───112___09    ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')
    │       └───112___10    ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')
    └───004=alpha9
        ├───DCIM
        │   └───101MSDCF    ('jpg')
        └───PRIVATE
            ├───AVCHD
            │   └───BDMV
            │       ├───CLIPINF
            │       ├───PLAYLIST
            │       └───STREAM      
            └───SONY
```

Comment: You seem to have unnecessary indentation on the last line

Comment: fixed. thank you. still error.

Comment: What's the exact and full error that you see?

Comment: `os.path.join(path, "%s" % timestr+'_'+f)) SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small typos in your code
1. In line 5 it should be `'g7'` instead of `'ng7'`
2. `convert_time_to_human_readable` is only defined in `get_last_write_time(filename)` and cannot be used outside it.
3. You are missing a `,` in second last line.
4. Instead of using `timestr` in last line you should use `get_last_write_time(f)`

```
import os

config = {
    'nd5': {},
    'g7': {},
    'alpha9': {},
}
config['nd5']['media_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')
config['g7']['media_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')
config['alpha9']['media_file'] = ('jpg')    

root = "."     
def get_last_write_time(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    convert_time_to_human_readable = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
    return convert_time_to_human_readable

for camID in config:
    for dir in next(os.walk(root))[1]:
        if dir.endswith(camID):
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)):
                for f in files:
                    if any([f.lower().endswith(x) for x in config[camID]["media_file"]]):
                        os.rename(os.path.join(path, f),os.path.join(path, "%s" % get_last_write_time(os.path.join(path, f))+'_'+f))
```

Comment: thank you. i am getting 2 errors: `<module> os.rename(os.path.join(path, f),os.path.join(path, "%s" % get_last_write_time(f)+'_'+f))   AND   in get_last_write_time st = os.stat(filename) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '23845.JPG'` should the `filename` need definition?

Comment: `'23845.JPG'` seems to be the first media file in the tree that needs to be processed. if this helps to debug.

Comment: try using `next(os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)))` in line 21

Comment: i am using whatever is in your answer above. getting error: `line 21, in <module> for path, dirs, files in next(os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir))): ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: i think `get_last_write_time(filename)` could not find the file so i have edited it and removed next i added in previous edit

Comment: `line 24, in <module> os.rename(os.path.join(path, f),os.path.join(path, "%s" % get_last_write_time(os.path.join(path, f))+'_'+f))   AND   in get_last_write_time convert_time_to_human_readable = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime)) NameError: name 'time' is not defined`